# Obter id de elemento gerado dinamicamente (BeginCollectionItem)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Possuo uma `View`, onde eu pego o valor selecionado em um `DropDownList`, utilizo esse valor em uma consulta `ajax` e povoo um outro `DropDownList` com o retorno da consulta. Até essa parte, tudo bem. Porém, esses `DropDownList's` serão gerados dinamicamente, usando o [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/), com isso, gerando um `id` diferente para cada item gerado.
Com isso, preciso obter esse valor, para enviar como parâmetro em minhas consultas.

Em Minha `view`, estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ClientesPrestacoes"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Cliente.CidadeId)
     <div class="form-group col-md-9 col-lg-offset-1">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Conjunto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-2 editor-field">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Conjunto,  new { @class = "clickConjunto" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Conjunto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div id="divClienteConjuntoAdd">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClienteConjuntoId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4 editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClienteConjuntoId, new SelectList(""), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ClienteConjuntoP" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClienteConjuntoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "ClienteConjuntoId" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <input type="button" class="removebtn btn btn-danger col-md-1" value="X" id="removebtn" title="Excluir Pretação" style="width: 30px" />
    </div>
}
```

O que é me gerado em `html` é esse:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-9 col-lg-offset-1">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ClientesPrestacoes_ca186a13-315c-46e4-b7b3-b2dd3063ddb4__Conjunto">Cliente Conjunto?</label>
    <div class="col-md-2 editor-field">
        <input class="clickConjunto" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo Cliente Conjunto? é obrigatório." id="ClientesPrestacoes_ca186a13-315c-46e4-b7b3-b2dd3063ddb4__Conjunto" name="ClientesPrestacoes[ca186a13-315c-46e4-b7b3-b2dd3063ddb4].Conjunto" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="ClientesPrestacoes[ca186a13-315c-46e4-b7b3-b2dd3063ddb4].Conjunto" type="hidden" value="false">
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ClientesPrestacoes[ca186a13-315c-46e4-b7b3-b2dd3063ddb4].Conjunto" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="divClienteConjuntoAdd">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ClientesPrestacoes_ca186a13-315c-46e4-b7b3-b2dd3063ddb4__ClienteConjuntoId">Nome Cliente</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 editor-field">
            <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Nome Cliente must be a number." id="ClienteConjuntoP" name="ClientesPrestacoes[ca186a13-315c-46e4-b7b3-b2dd3063ddb4].ClienteConjuntoId"></select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ClientesPrestacoes[ca186a13-315c-46e4-b7b3-b2dd3063ddb4].ClienteConjuntoId" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="ClienteConjuntoId"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cada novo item, me gera um `id` diferente.

Necessito recuperar o `id` para utilizar como parâmetro em minha consulta `ajax`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.clickConjunto').change(function () {
    var checkId = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(@cidadeId);
    if (document.getElementById(checkId).checked == true) {
        document.getElementById('divClienteConjuntoAdd').style.display = 'block';
        $.getJSON(BASE_URL + 'Cliente/ObterClientePorCidade', { cidadeId: @cidadeId }, function (data) {

            $('#ClienteConjuntoIdP option').remove();
            console.log('teste');
            if (data.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#ClienteConjuntoIdP').append('<option value="' +
                        data[i].ClienteId + '"> ' +
                        data[i].NomeEntidade + '</option>');
                }
            } else {
                $('#ClienteConjuntoIdP option').remove();
                $('#ClienteConjuntoIdP').append('<option> Essa cidade não possui Prefeituras</option>');
            }

        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById('divClienteConjuntoAdd').style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

O valor do `checkBox` eu recupero ao clicar no mesmo. Faço isso nessa parte:

```
$('.clickConjunto').change(function () {
        var checkId = $(this).attr('id');
```

O problema, é recuperar o `id` do `DorpDownList` gerado. Esse eu não poderei utilizar o evento `click()` ou `change()` para recuperar o valor.

Tentei utilizar algo como:

```
 var id = $(@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClienteConjuntoId, new SelectList(""))).attr('id');
```

Mas recebo erro.

Comment: Tens partes do código redundantes e desnecessárias, mas acho que o problema principal é delegação. Funciona se usares o `.change()` desta maneira? -> `$(document).on('change', '.clickConjunto', function () {`

Comment: @Sergio Então, esse código está "meio sujo", pois está minhas tentativas. Da forma que você falou funciona também, porém ele recupera somente o valor do `checkBox`, e isso já estava fazendo. Preciso recuperar o valor do `DropDownList`, para utilizar dentro do `for()` e povoar o mesmo.

Comment: O que queres dizer com "povoar o DropDownList"? vais fazer isso no JS ou servidor? e "Preciso recuperar o valor do DropDownList"? quando há um change ou quando é adicionado ao documento?

Comment: Se o `BeginCollectionItem` é `ClientesPrestacoes`, não faz sentido que você esteja buscando um Id aleatório, até porque se você faz uma busca, a ideia é que a pesquisa traga uma Id que não existe. Como está o código do seu *Controller*?

Comment: @Sergio Ao clicar no `checkbox` ele faz uma consulta `ajax` e retorna a lista como `option` do `DropDownList`.
"Povoar": Preencher, carregar, popular com dados retornados da consulta `ajax`.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Me desculpe, me expressei muito mal. O id que me refiro, não é o de `ClientePrestacoes`, e sim o id do [Html Elemento](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp). Ou seja, o id do `DropDownList` (id=" ")

Comment: [Esta pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20359332/4843158) no SOen, o usuário está com o mesmo problema. Caso eu não tenha me expressado bem, essa pergunta poderá ajudar a "clarear".
Obs.: Ela também não possui resposta.